# Visual Studio Code not automatically create bin folder, file .classpath and file .settings for java language

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I have some problem in visual studio code :

1. Visual studio code for java not create **folder bin, file .classpath, .project and .settings automatically**.
   Sreenshoot :
   [In explorer VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNoTJ.jpg)
2. File app.java and app.class in the same folder (src), when I look tutorials in youtube, file **.class** should be in bin folder.
3. In **settings.json** there is **file.exclude**, when I change **.classpath** to the false or delete it. It always reset to the true again. But if I run my code. it works.
   Screenshoot : [settings.json file (user)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t78D.jpg)

Can someone help? I've search in any forum but never found solution and make sure path in my environment is correct!

Windows 10, VSC 1.53.0, jdk 15 (latest)

## Edited

I ask this question when I'm very new with Java, now I understand, some file like .classpath, .project and etc will show when I use build tools like gradle or maven. Maybe because tutorial on youtube use old vscode version and not explain more about this file, actually this is like dumb question. But maybe this can help someone that new in Java too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project is newly created in VS Code through the command `Java: Create Java Project...`. This command will create a new project without build tools. (No Maven and Gradle). In that case, the files such as `.classpath`, `.project`, etc... will be hidden in the workspace storage path, which is by design, since we want the user just focus on the code itself.

If you want to see the `bin` folder, there is a setting called `java.project.outputPath`, you can set a relative path to that setting, then the output folder will be explicitly show in your project. For example: `"java.project.outputPath": "bin"`

> Note, the setting `java.project.outputPath` only takes effect in the workspace scope.

Comment: Could you share more details about why you want to show these files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not interested at the youtube tutorials, but the folder structure in vscode-java is indeed like what you see.

In integrated Terminal, there'll a series of execution scripts shown before the real output. The one ends of folder **bin** is also the current project's **classpath**. The `.class` files which is generated by being compiled are stored there.

Setting.json is stored under the folder **.vscode**. This is your workspace setting, which is generated by pressing `Ctrl+,` and choosing workspace.

[image]

Comment: [Running] cd "c:\Users\asus\Documents\Sasmita\Coding\Java\javaku2\src\" && javac App.java && java App
Hello, World!                                                                                            My output is shown like that

Comment: Uninstall the extension **Code Runner**, cause i run the java file from the button provided by **java extension pack**.